# calculate new coordinates having one coordinates + distance in X and Y and Z direction

Tags: android, gps, coordinates, gis

There is a real GPS point :

```
   <GPS>
          <latitude>36.1319779627</latitude>
          <longitude>-115.154950231</longitude>
          <altitude>621.5</altitude>
          <heading>0.0</heading>
    </GPS>
```

and then there are a list on points based on distance from this real GPS point :

```
<control_point_list>
                       <control_point>
                            <X>-2310.41411189</X>
                            <Y>32.4828342845</Y>
                            <Z>-164.167976564</Z>
                        </control_point>
                        <control_point>
                            <X>-2322.09317395</X>
                            <Y>32.4422985598</Y>
                            <Z>-172.301188413</Z>
                        </control_point>
                        <control_point>
                            <X>-2332.96313438</X>
                            <Y>32.3349680574</Y>
                            <Z>-179.876134127</Z>
                        </control_point>
</control_point_list>
```

How should I calculate the coordinates of new points?

Comment: What had you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried formula from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477003/calculating-new-longtitude-latitude-from-old-n-meters      but results are not accurate, same area but not true

Comment: new_latitude  = latitude  + (dy / r_earth) * (180 / pi);
new_longitude = longitude + (dx / r_earth) * (180 / pi) / cos(latitude * pi/180);

Comment: you have to live with that (because earth is not a ball) or do some more research ...

Comment: http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/PUBS_LIB/inverse.pdf , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System

Comment: Thank you very much, I was wondering if you could tell me what dy and dx means in above formula? I took them as distance but I guess I'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

Soluition given in this link works fine. 
In my case there was a problem with data provider and not the formula.

[Calculating new longtitude, latitude from old + n meters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477003/calculating-new-longtitude-latitude-from-old-n-meters)