# Calculating new latitude and longitude from old + n meters + heding

Tags: algorithm, geolocation

I need to calculate new geo location from known current latitude, longitude, offset in meters, and heading. I found this answer [Calculating new longtitude, latitude from old + n meters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477003/calculating-new-longtitude-latitude-from-old-n-meters), it's works, but does not take into account the direction(heading).
Please give some tip/advise!

Comment: I would recommend you to use ready packages for those calculations, like  `geopy` in python.

Comment: Split your vector into a north-south and an east-west component (sin and cos of the bearing), then use the question you linked to.