# Add X meters in Latitude and Longitude and generate new latitude and longitude in PHP

Tags: php, latitude-longitude, google-latitude

Suppose I have latitude= 21.15490584 and longitude= 79.04627271 and add X meters, am I able to calculate new coordinates?

Comment: Is this a trigonometry or a programming question? From what I see, it's the former.

Comment: its an programing question for me and have to find solution in php!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating new longitude, latitude from old + n meters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477003/calculating-new-longitude-latitude-from-old-n-meters)

Answer (score 0):

I think this one is worked for you...

Can you please check [this...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40471701/9238777)

```html
<?php
$meters = 30;
$coef = $meters * 0.0000089;
echo $new_lat = 13.0406067 + $coef;
echo "<br>";
echo $new_long = 80.1925414 + $coef / cos(13.0406067 * 0.018);
?>
```

In the above example i have added 30 meters...

Comment: what is 0.0000089 value stands for ?? and can we find out angle, i mean in what angle the lat long stands for ? 30meters in which direction?