# Draw marker on Google Map at specific positions

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have created a small tool using Google map API javascript. It takes the place name as input and when form is submitted, it places marker at that location. That's very basic usage. But what I want to achieve is,

1. take that location's latitude-longitude as base and make it as marker in center(which is done already)
2. place one marker 10 miles away from center to the top position
3. Place one marker 10 miles away from center to the bottom position
4. Place one marker 10 miles away from center to the left position
5. Place one marker 10 miles away from center to the right position

So basically there will be total 5 markers. one in center and 4 on top, bottom, left and right position at exactly 10 miles distance. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477003/calculating-new-longitude-latitude-from-old-n-meters

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio, it might be a duplicate but the answer provided there isn't good. It uses a fixed radius which is not precise as the Earth is not round. See my answer below for an easier and precise calculation provided by the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Maps JS API has a Geometry library. You need to include it in the API call:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry`

The [spherical namespace](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geometry#spherical) contains a [`computeOffset()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geometry#spherical.computeOffset) method which allows to pass your coordinates, a distance and a heading.

`0/360°` = North, `90°` = East, `180°` = South, etc.

So if you want to compute a point at **10 km East from the coordinates `0,0`** you can do:

```
let point = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(new google.maps.LatLng(0,0), 10000, 90);
```

Distance is passed in meters so you can simply multiply your distance in miles by `1609,34`.

More information here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#Geometry

Proof of concept:

```js
var map;

function initMap() {

  let center = new google.maps.LatLng(53.051185, -2.492474);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: center
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: center,
    map: map,
  });

  addMarker(center, 1000, 0);
  addMarker(center, 1000, 90);
  addMarker(center, 1000, 180);
  addMarker(center, 1000, 270);
}

function addMarker(coords, offset, heading) {

  let point = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(coords, offset, heading);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: point,
    map: map,
  });
}

initMap();
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I found where the issue was. Your answer didn't work for me first and you said "you are not a wizard". I felt offensive so I downvoted it. The issue was the I was reverse geocoding each marker point before placing them on Map as I wanted to retrieve addresses of those markers. And in the it was doing something wrong. So I just removed the geocoding part and it fixed using your code only. I will upvote it and mark it as right answer. Thanks again.

Comment: I wasn't trying to be offensive but you should know that just posting a screenshot and saying it doesn't work is not helpful to others and especially to people who are trying to help you... Take it easy!