# how to add 500meters to a lat and long in Python

Tags: python, latitude-longitude, google-latitude

If this is the initial

```
Latitude:  13.050249
Longitude:  77.462143
```

how to increment the lat and long by 500m and get the new pixel/grid's coordinates?

Comment: This is a question which is already fully answered. Please look up, if a question of this kind is already existing instead creating a new one. And please add more informations to your question. Which Grid do you mean?

See here: [Calculating new longitude, latitude from old + n meters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477003/calculating-new-longitude-latitude-from-old-n-meters)

Comment: Whithout  a statement, in which direction the 500 meters have to be added, this can't be answered. Other basic facts are also missing (Earth, Moon, Jupiter, ...). What means  "pixel" here?

Comment: I have to increment longitude by 500meters towards east and increment latitude by 500meters towards south for any particular city. Pixels/grids are new incremented lat and long.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function to it you can pass the x and y to get lat and long.

```
from math import cos
from math import radians
def meters_2_lat_lon(m, orig_lat):
    lat = m/111111
    lon = m/(111111 * cos(radians(orig_lat)))
    return lat, lon
```