# Is there a way to rotate a dash-leaflet dl.Rectangle() through a callback?

Tags: python, rotation, plotly-dash, dash-leaflet

I'm building an python dash-leaflet app where the user can click on a map to place a rectangle through a callback, and I would like to add a second callback (bond to a slider) to rotate it around its center according to North (eg. rotate it by 20° to the East).

To place the rectangle in a callback I use:

```py
mapOne.append(dl.Rectangle(fillOpacity=0.5, weight=0.7, color='#888',
        bounds=[[click_lat_lng[0]+xbox1, click_lat_lng[1]+ybox1],
                        [click_lat_lng[0]+xbox2, click_lat_lng[1]+ybox2]]
             ))
```

I thought about a sort of inverse Haversine function to get the new "rotated" `xbox1` and `xbox2`, but the `dl.Rectangle()` seem to be always aligned with axes.

Any thought on the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I never figured out a ay to do it "out of the box" with `dash-leaflet` in **python** (though it seems fairly easy with `leaflet` and some built-in functions in **js**).

I ended up using a `dl.polygon()` instead, using :

- the center of my rectangle defined by `click_lat_lng[0]` and `click_lat_lng[1]`,
- The dimensions of my rectangle defined in meters, together with a simple [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) to define the actual "rotated" x and y of the rectangle corners,
- Finally translating this to lat / lon values with the help  of the following function (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477003/calculating-new-longitude-latitude-from-old-n-meters/69713865#69713865)) :

```py
def translate_latlong(lat,long,lat_translation_meters,long_translation_meters):
    ''' method to move any lat,long point by provided meters in lat and long direction.
    params :
        lat,long: lattitude and longitude in degrees as decimal values, e.g. 37.43609517497065, -122.17226450150885
        lat_translation_meters: movement of point in meters in lattitude direction.
                                positive value: up move, negative value: down move
        long_translation_meters: movement of point in meters in longitude direction.
                                positive value: left move, negative value: right move
        '''
    earth_radius = 6378.137

    #Calculate top, which is lat_translation_meters above
    m_lat = (1 / ((2 * math.pi / 360) * earth_radius)) / 1000;  
    lat_new = lat + (lat_translation_meters * m_lat)

    #Calculate right, which is long_translation_meters right
    m_long = (1 / ((2 * math.pi / 360) * earth_radius)) / 1000;  # 1 meter in degree
    long_new = long + (long_translation_meters * m_long) / math.cos(lat * (math.pi / 180));
    
    return lat_new,long_new
```