# A new coordinate 50metres away from another in C#, how?

Tags: c#, gps, maps, coordinates, calculus

I have a coordinate and a heading, how do I get a second coordinate say 50 metres away from the first one in a C# function?

Example info:

```
Lat: 56.33908260  
Lon: 17.01194088

Radians:             -1.7453292519943295  
RadiansToDegrees:     57.295779513082323  
GeographicalDegrees: -170.0  
MathematicalDegrees: -100.00
```

Comment: Do you assume the world is a sphere (most models don't)? Do you measure the distance as a straight line, or along the surface? And in which direction should your new point be? There is a complete circle of such points.

Comment: Like the solution Markus Palme wrote below, maybe you have an even simpler function. Along the surface I guess and the direction I wrote in the example info.

Comment: I don't see any direction in your example. But I don't get your example in the first place. You still didn't state if you consider earth a sphere.

Comment: The last four lines is the direction in different formats. If it is a sphere according to WGS 84 then yes, else no.

Comment: WSG 84 is based on a reference ellipsoid which comes pretty close to the earth's actual shape. I would assume a sphere if accuracy is not that important (e.g. if the distances are rather small), if not use a more complex model like WSG 84.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the geodetic system you are using/want to use.

> Geodetic systems or geodetic data are used [...] to translate positions indicated on their products to their real position on earth.

One of the most commonly used systems is WGS 84.

Some background:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720/how-to-calculate-a-heading-on-the-earths-surface

What you are looking for looks like the "Direct problem" to me.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty's_formulae#Direct_Problem

Here you can find an implementation in C++ which should be rather easy to port (respect the licence):

https://github.com/pkohut/GeoFormulas/blob/master/GeoFormulas/VincentyDestination.cpp

This implementation is derived from this formula:
http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-vincenty-direct.html

Answer (score 0):

Not really a field I'm familiar with, but i'd look at how to calculate miles using latitude & longitude and turn that into a function.

Post some code of what you have tried, then we can take it from there?

**EDIT** : Possible answer

[How do I find the lat/long that is x km north of a given lat/long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125144/how-do-i-find-the-lat-long-that-is-x-km-north-of-a-given-lat-long)