# Calculate Next Lat Long

Tags: math, latitude-longitude

If you are given a distance in Nautical mile and you have initial Lat Long how can you calculate next lat long?

i have initial lat 30.2735 and initial long 68.4455 now i want to calculate the next lat long which should be at a distance of 30 NM. How can i calculate this any formula for this problem ?

Comment: This thread may be of help to you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125144/how-do-i-find-the-lat-long-that-is-x-km-north-of-a-given-lat-long

Answer (score 1):

You should also provide moving direction (bearing, azimuth). Then you can apply formula from [Destination point ...](http://Destination%20point%20given%20distance%20and%20bearing%20from%20start%20point) section

```
JavaScript:
(all angles 
in radians)
var φ2 = Math.asin( Math.sin(φ1)*Math.cos(d/R) +
                    Math.cos(φ1)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(brng) );
var λ2 = λ1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(φ1),
                         Math.cos(d/R)-Math.sin(φ1)*Math.sin(φ2));
```